# Calling RNGCrypto From COM's DOTNET Class From PHP

Tags: php, .net, com, reference, variant

I'm attempting to call RNGCryptoServiceProvider->GetBytes() from PHP via the COM layer.  I can get it to connect to the class, but every time I call the method, I get one of two errors (relating to the parameter).  I think it has something to due with the fact that GetBytes takes a fixed size byte array by reference.  Since PHP doesn't support fixed sized strings, that's where it gets interesting:

Error 1:

```
$util    = new \DOTNET(
    'mscorlib',
    'System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider'
);
$data = new \Variant(str_repeat(chr(46), $size), VT_UI1 | VT_ARRAY);
$util->GetBytes($data);
```

> Error [0x80070057] The parameter is incorrect

Which is thrown by the `->GetBytes()` line.

If I don't use a variant, but just use a plain string, I still get the same error.

However, if I pass in an array like so:

```
$data = array('');
$util->GetBytes($data);
```

> Parameter 0: Type mismatch.

So I think the variant/string approach is the correct one (as it passes the parameter type check).  But I just can't figure out how to get it working.

The [C# interface to the method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider.getbytes.aspx#) is:

```
public override void GetBytes(
    byte[] data
)
```

Thanks

Comment: It may be not the solution you are looking for but why not create a simple windows service that receives whatever you want to send from PHP and then just return the value encoded (do all the processing in C#)?

Comment: @GustavoRubio this is for library code. Actually part of a portable PRNG that attempts to produce strong randomness on all platforms. So services or anything other than system calls are not really acceptable (for what I'm doing). Nice idea though...

Answer (score 3):

It has been years since I touched PHP, let alone tried to interop with .net, but what if you create a string padded to your desired length and unpack() it?

```
$byte_array = unpack('C*', '12345678');
$util->GetBytes($byte_array);
```

---

Whelp, wasted an hour or two playing with it to no result. I'd take a look at this:

http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?766246-PHP-and-NET-Secure-RndNum-Generation-using-DOTNET-class

Two reasonable options there - build a simple wrapper of some kind so you can just call a parameterless method, or use something built in and cross-platform.

Comment: Thanks man. I already came across that thread.. I was looking for a Windows solution for when `mcrypt` is disabled.

Comment: From a practical standpoint, yes, using `mcrypt_create_iv` or a custom wrapper object would be useful in a specific application. This question is more for a generic usage, where you can't install a wrapper object (no access) and you can't control if mcrypt is installed or not (also no access)... Since COM is enabled, hopefully there would be a method to do this...

Comment: here, take the bounty anyways for trying :P